# Asp.net GridView How to convert to decimal in footer row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and this has a textbox in footerrow.I want to insert database.But I getting error.How to convert decimal? My value is decimal in database.My error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error converting data type nvarchar to
>   numeric.

Cs.code:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["MIKTAR"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)grdSiparisHar.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMiktar")).Text;
```

aspx code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdSiparisHar" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True">
                    <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MIKTAR" SortExpression="MIKTAR">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MIKTAR") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MIKTAR") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                              <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiktar" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.I added type=decimal in sqldatasource

```
<InsertParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="MIKTAR" Type="Decimal"></asp:Parameter>
</InsertParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["MIKTAR"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)grdSiparisHar.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMiktar")).Text);
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string' I getting this error.

Comment: what do you insert your textbox?

Comment: like 7.25 not decimal